# How to delete a line in tkinter when it is an attribute of a class

Tags: python, tkinter, line, tkinter-canvas

I'm currently creating a game in which should be a cross moving in a canvas. I have written the binding to the arrow keys and I have also written the code to create a new cross(w. two lines, because of that my question).

But now I keep getting stuck. I have written a simple `player`-class, in which I store the coordinates and the root-canvas as attibutes. To draw the two lines nessecary for this I have the function `draw`, to change the place the function `configure`

Here is the code I have now:

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.root = None
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.l1 = root.create_line(self.x-5, self.y-5, self.x+5, self.y+5,  width=2)
        self.l2 = root.create_line(self.x+5, self.y-5, self.x-5, self.y+5,  width=2)

    def configure(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.root.create_line(self.x-5, self.y-5, self.x+5, self.y+5,  width=2)
        self.root.create_line(self.x+5, self.y-5, self.x-5, self.y+5,  width=2)
```

In `configure`, I can draw new lines without problems, but if I try to delete `self.l1` and `self.l2`, I keep getting error messages, python says, they would be integers?! Why does it do that and how can I delete my old lines?

Comment: Canvas elements index is integer. Example: Can you call `self.root.itemconfig(index,which_allowed_options_args)` and don't delete element reconfigure for reuse.

Comment: `self.root.delete("all")` if root a canvas !

Comment: @dsgdfg: That worked! Thank you so much

Comment: Why don't ask me "why don't delete canvas elements ?" But answer is: You got big id numbers if delete and create new. it's not problem if you have few canvas element. Like this : got 100ms period and create 1.2 K elements. Got 9-12 digit index number(untraceable).  When a element don't need `hide`, replace arguments and display it as new element. Got better performance if used related method ! @erich-schmidt